# Find first div without the class and then add a class

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<div class="tab-wrap">
   <div class="tab-item sold-out" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">Tab 1</div>
   <div class="tab-item sold-out"  aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Tab 2</div>
   <div class="tab-item sold-out" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Tab 3</div>
   <div class="tab-item" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Tab 4</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to select the first ".tab-item" not containing the class ".sold-out" and add a class ".active" to it. This might vary, sometimes it might be the first div other times the third. I want to check for the first available div without the class sold-out.

What I have, this is adds it to the first div regardless of whether it has the class "sold-out" on it:

```
if($(".tab-wrap > .tab-item").not(':has(.sold-out)')){
  $(".tab-wrap > .tab-item").first().addClass("active")
}
```

Comment: Worth reviewing what `:has` does https://api.jquery.com/has/ *Reduce the set of matched elements to those that **have a descendant** that matches the selector or DOM element.* - .tab-item doesn't have .sold-out as a descendant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you need in a single selector using a combination of `:not` and `:first`. Try this:

```js
$('.tab-item:not(.sold-out):first').addClass('sold-out');
```

```css
.sold-out { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-wrap">
  <div class="tab-item sold-out" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab-item sold-out" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab-item sold-out" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="tab-item" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Tab 4 (class added here)</div>
  <div class="tab-item" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Tab 5</div>
  <div class="tab-item" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Tab 6</div>
  <div class="tab-item" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Tab 7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what you want just in single line with both selector's

```
$('.tab-item:not(.sold-out):first').addClass('sold-out');
```